# Can I build a word ‘Stoßtweet’ to be used instead of ‘Stoßgetweet’?

Tags: word-choice

When reading a *taz.de* article "[Lange ist nicht mehr so viel passiert](http://taz.de/Kolumne-Jung--Dumm/!5321833/)", I came across a word *Stoßgetweet*. It occurs in the introductory paragraph of the article:

> Früher war mehr Lametta. Heute ist mehr Lamento. Über Augstein [Jakob Augstein, a German journalist], Autobahn-Hühner und das überbordende **Stoßgetweete**.

and in the final paragraph:

> Im Gegenteil: Noch viel zu viele unschuldige Seelen laufen da draußen (gleichzeitig) rum und schnuppern an Blumen, statt Augstein zu folgen. Denn in Zeiten wie diesen ist es wohl nur noch das „Hallo, hier bin ich“, das beherzte **Stoßgetweet**, das uns von dem Bösen zu erlösen vermag.

Google search seems to indicate that the word *Stoßgetweet* has been used for the first time ever in the above-referenced *taz.de* article.

Would a word *Stoßtweet* (I just came up with it) be an appropriate replacement for *Stoßgetweet*? Also, what's the meaning of *Stoßgetweet*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Stoßgetweet* (very nice find, BTW) lives from its resemblance to *Stoßgebet* (look that up) and is thus understandable for a native speaker as a desperate plea to twitter for help or support (as opposed to a desperate prayer to god).

If you change it to *Stoßtweet*, you remove too much (IMHO) of this resemblance to still have something anyone would understand. (But that is very much opinion-based). Even if German allows you to build your own words using known grammar structures and rules, you should still stay within a "limited range of obviousness" on what your new word means to say - And I think "Stoßtweet" stretches it a bit too far. You could also not expect to be able to shorten *Stoßgebet* to *Stoßbet*, that leaves you with unintelligible rubbish. OTOH, non-internet affine speakers wouldn't even understand *Stoßgetweet*.

Most of the article is, very hard to understand for a non-native, mostly because of its many hidden cross-references. Did you get the "Früher war mehr Lametta" part? That is a citation of an old [Loriot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo55jk0HFWA) sketch. And if you didn't get the "Autobahn-Hühner" part, that is a reference to [this article](http://www.welt.de/regionales/sachsen/article156911281/Problemhuhn-Gerda-lebt-auf-der-Autobahn-in-Dresden.html).

Comment: Definitely right, I wouldn't even say opinion based. Stosstweet will not spark the connection!

Comment: @tofro This was one of the very few articles I had to read twice to understand it. You are right, reference to "Lametta" wasn't clear to me. From a dictionary, I could see that the talk was either about military medals or about long narrow strips for Christmas decoration. But why the reference at all, that was Greek to me. I actually could figure out the part with the "Autobahn-Hühner" from context in the body of the article, but your link makes it finally clear what the talk was actually about (Thanks!). Some articles in taz.de are really challenging, especially in the "Wahrheit" section.

Comment: The Loriot quote "früher war mehr Lametta" has become a phrase. It means something like "I don't have a real reason to dislike something, but I don't like it anyway, so I complain about *something*". It's mostly used in a (self-)mocking fashion. In the taz article, it's used differently, namely in a word play: "Lametta" - "Lamento" ("lamentation"). A translation, loosing the joke completely, would be "Back then, we had more tinsel. Today, we have more complaining".

Comment: I disagree that it's directly relating to _Stoßgebet_, rather generally to the prefix _Stoß-_ (_Stoßzeit_, _Stoßverkehr_, _Stoßbetrieb_, ...), meaning something reaching peak (or high-volume, extreme) times [i.e. _Stoßgebet_ is a prayer in a peak situation]. Ther shouldn't be any emotions connected in general. _Stoßgetweet_ accordingly should mean much tweeting in a relatively short time. _Stoßtweeten_ would thus signify that you are tweeting many messages at once.

Comment: @bwoebi "das beherzte Stoßgetweet, das uns von dem Bösen zu erlösen vermag." very clearly hints to *Stoßgebet* and not to "mass tweeting"

Comment: @tofro I'm not sure. In the introduction "das überbordende Stoßgetweete" hints to _Stoß-_ in general. I guess it's probably used in both senses.

Comment: Your argument about it never being a *Stoßbet* is a very weak one since the word *Bet* in itself does not exist, but *Tweet* does.

Answer (score 1):

Both *Stoßgetweete* and *Stoßtweet* have their justifications. I stumbled across the form *Stoßgetweet* but I can totally see its (admittedly much weaker) justification, too.

Let’s start off with (the singular word) *das Stoßgetweete*. The site is called *Twitter*, the German verb for *to tweet* is *tweeten* and in the same way as transforming *reden* into *Gerede* or *fragen* into *Gefrage*, we can derive *das Getweete* for a series of random, unimportant, unnerving, or whatever else you want to add here tweets. If that happens ‘shotwise’ (*stoßweise*, e.g. #Aufschrei), you can be inclined to call it *Stoßgetweete*. I wouldn’t use it in a positively worded sentence.

Now a single tweet, would be just that in German, too: *ein Tweet*. Don’t ask me whether the verb lost a shwa or whether *tweeten* was derived from the noun. All that I can definitely note is that contrary to nouns like *Frage, Rede, Bitte,* etc., this word does not end with an *e*. If you blurted out a single tweet in a similar way to the wave of tweets mentioned above, that could be called a *Stoßtweet*. (Or maybe it was just a Tweet that was supposed to shove somebody/something in a certain direction, up to you to decide!)

Let’s finally consider *Stoßgetweet*. I do not consider this a well-formed word, unlike *Stoßtweet* and *Stoßgetweete*, which I would immediately accept. However, it kind of makes sense in the context you give by alluding to the *Stoßgebet*. I would consider this a malformed word for generating effect, though. I doubt too many people would have connected *Stoßtweet* to *Stoßgebet* while *Stoßgetweet* immediately suggests such a connection.
The thing I dislike most about it is the seemingly extraneous *-ge-*. As mentioned above, I deem *Stoßtweet* to be a good enough word and I don’t deem *Getweet* to be acceptable. The prefix *ge-* is a pretty common one in German, especially due to it marking past participles. I’m not sure about whether the *ge-* in *Gebet* is one of those, though and that is the weak basis that that analogy is built upon.

tl;dr: No, you cannot choose your grammatical rules to make up words, but if there is a sufficiently strong analogy, you can get away with some misformings better than with others.