# Warum sprechen wir von einem »Gebet«?

Tags: etymology, noun, prefix

[Diese Frage zum *Stoßgetweete* und *Stoß**ge**tweet*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31201) hat mich auf eine Folgefrage gestoßen: Woher stammt eigentlich das *Ge-* in *Gebet*?

Die Analogien, die ich mir auf die Schnelle aufgestellt habe, helfen dabei nicht weiter. Wenn ich etwas frage, ist das eine *Frage*. Wenn ich zu vielen Leuten (in gewissem, formalen Rahmen) rede, ist das eine *Rede*. Wenn ich jemanden um einen Gefallen bitte, ist das eine *Bitte*. Es sei denn, dieser Jemand ist der Höchste, in welchem Fall es ein *Gebet* ist, das ich aber *bete* (ohne *ge-*).

Zurück zum *Gefallen*, auch dort ist ein Verb vertreten, dessen Stamm ursprünglich kein *ge-* gehabt hat. Aber dessen Vorsilbe ist längst untrennbar geworden: »Das gefällt mir« und »das hat mir gefallen« (nicht: *<strike>gegefallen</strike>*), ähnlich dem Begleiter und begleiten.

Ein weiterer Anhaltspunkt für eine Vorsilbe *ge-* wären Formen wie *Gewese, Gerede, Gefrage* usw. Allerdings sollte *das Gebete* viel besser in diese Reihe passen, es müsste sich also um eine andere Bildungsregel handeln.

Bleiben vielleicht noch Wörter wie *Gemächt, Gericht, Gewicht, Gesicht*. Hier scheint es sich zumindest manchmal um ähnliche Bildungsregeln (insbesondere scheint sich *Gericht* zu *richten* ähnlich zu verhalten wie *Gebet* zu *beten*) aber eine wirkliche Regel kann ich darin auch nicht erkennen.

Wie erklärt sich also die Vorsilbe *ge-* des *Gebets*? Sind die Formen im letzten Absatz analog gebildet? Gibt es noch viele weitere solcher Formen? Welche Hinweise liefert die Etymologie?

Comment: Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gebet) stammt "Gebet" von althochdeutsch "gibet" bzw. mittelhochdeutch "gebet" für die "Bitte". Das Verb "beten" entstand erst später. Demzufolge kam nicht die Vorsilbe bei "Gebet" dazu, sondern sie ist später bei anderen Formen weggefallen.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Das ist sehr relevant und beantwortet die Frage. Schreib es doch als Antwort!

Comment: Geläut, Gericht und Gesicht erscheinen mir ähnlich. Aber vielleicht verstehe ich die Frage nur nicht richtig...

Comment: @KilianFoth Em1 hat bereits eine Antwort geschrieben, die meine Argumentation enthält, da brauche ich nicht nochmal etwas sehr Ähnliches zu schreiben :) Aber danke für den Vorschlag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gebet leitet sich nicht von beten ab!

Quelle 1: [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/gebet:N:N)

> ge + bitten -> Gebet

Quelle 2: [Grimm'sche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG02674#XGG02674)

> GEBET, m. preces, subst. zu bitten.
>
> es ist nicht von beten, zu dem es das heutige sprachgefühl zieht, sondern von bitten, wie es denn lange noch auch ein bitten bezeichnete; beten ist umgekehrt erst gebildet von bet (s. d., mhd. Loh. 1253), der einfachen form von gebet, die noch im 16. jh. nicht vergessen war, nicht oberd. blosz, wo in bet das ge- geschwunden sein könnte

Ich tue mich schwer damit, alles genau zu verstehen. Aber hier noch einige weitere dort genannte Aspekte, die man im Kontext der Frage mal beachten sollte. Auch wenn sich da einige weitere Ungewissheiten und Fragen auftuen dürften.

- Im Weiteren wird dort auch die *Fürbitte* erwähnt, ein Synonym zu *Gebet*. Diese hat kein *Ge-* davor.
- Es scheint auch mal eine Form *gebeten* und *gebiten* gegeben zu haben, wenngleich auch als selten eingestuft.
- Ein gibt das Wortpaar *bieten* und *Gebot*, wo das Nomen vom Verb abgeleitet ist. Hier gibt es aber auch noch *gebieten*.

Warum nun die Vorsilbe *Ge-* lässt sich anscheinend aber nur vermuten.

> dasz die ge-form beim subst. allein auf dem platze blieb, während sie bei beten und bitten nicht aufkam, das ist auffallend und musz in der bedeutung seinen grund haben, gebet vielleicht als anhaltendes bitten gemeint.

Und hier noch am Rande erwähnt, dass mein erster Gedanke bei deinem zweiten Absatz war, dass anhaltenes Fragen als Gefrage bezeichnet wird und anhaltenes Reden ist bekanntlich Gerede. Wenngleich beides hier eine negative Konnotation aufweist, das Gebet jedoch eher neutral bis positiv aufzufassen ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann das Problem nicht ganz nachvollziehen und bin zudem in der Formenlehre germanischer Sprachen wenig bewandert. Naiv erscheint mir das Gebet gar nicht so einzigartig:

- Gespräch / sprechen
- Gedicht / dichten
- Gesicht / sehen
- Gericht / richten
- Gefecht / fechten
- Gelächter / lachen
- Gewicht / wiegen (oder wichten?)
- Geleit / leiten
- Geflecht / flechten

Nun hat Herr Kockerbeck in den Kommentaren gezeigt, wie es sich mit *Gebet* im Speziellen verhält, das älter sei als *beten* (daraus sollte er eine Antwort machen). Ich denke aber, meine Liste zeigt, dass Substantive mit Ge- als Vorsilbe nicht selten sind! Wenn *Gebet* zudem älter ist als *beten*, könnte es zu dessen Entstehung geführt haben. Das wäre dann ein entscheidendes Argument für die Prevalenz dieses Musters im Mittelhochdeutschen! Damit meine ich: wenn ich aus einem Nomen nach diesem Muster ein Verb mache, muss mir diese Form der Ableitung - in welche Richtung auch immer - sehr vertraut sein.

Comment: Stimmt, die passen alle zu meiner letzten Vermutung. Sie sind mir bloß gestern Nacht nicht eingefallen (und den Duden, Seite *Ge*, aufschlagen wollte ich gestern wirklich nicht O:-))

Comment: @Jan gute Idee, daran habe ich gar nicht gedacht!